# If Condition Gives Syntax Error ( Python version 3.11 )

Tags: python-3.x, syntax-error

I am new in the Python, and I am trying to run a python code from Java with Jython.

This is the block which gives a syntax error.

```
def int_to_16bytesmultiplearray(value):
    """
    Encode an integer into a bytearray whose size will be a multiple of 16 bytes (i.e. 128bits)
    :param value:
    :return:
    """
    # special case. 0 has a zero bit length
    if value == 0:
        return int_to_16bytesarray(0)

    bitlen = value.bit_length()
    min_length = math.ceil(bitlen/8)
    if (rem := (min_length % 16)) > 0:
        extra = 16 - rem
    else:
        extra = 0

    return value.to_bytes(length=min_length+extra, byteorder="big")
```

The error I get is in this line :   if (rem := (min_length % 16)) != 0:

```
Error :  if (rem := (min_length % 16)) != 0:
            ^
SyntaxError: ("no viable alternative at input ':'")
```

Comment: The error you claim you get doesn't match the code you show. Please [edit] your question to show us a proper [mre]. And copy-paste (as text) the full and complete error output.

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude i updated the Question with the full error output

Comment: I'm sorry but it still doesn't match the code you show. If you don't show a proper [mre], or there is a mismatch between the code and the error, then how can we reliably help you? While the code you show looks *almost* like the one in the error message, perhaps you actually have an exact match in the part of your code that you *don't* show? All error messages should contain a line number, does the line number in the actual error output match the one in the code you show?